# Как сделать так, чтобы консольная программа не закрывалась. Язык Си. Программа - Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello\n");
  printf("world\n");
  return 0;
}
//Мне нужно что бы консоль при запуске программы не закрывалась сразу же
```

Comment: Перейти в linux

Comment: Запускать ее из консоли, а не из окошка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добавьте функцию `_getch()` - она будет ожидать нажатия какой-нибудь (любой) клавиши

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello\n");
  printf("world\n");

  _getch();
  return 0;
}
```